# Capturing Rails 3 Multiselect Input Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionpack

I have a multiselect form control (fig. 1). When I select more than 1 value, Firefox sends both values (fig. 2). But only the last value gets sent as a input value to my controller (fig. 3). How do I get all those values passed on to my controller?

```
  <form action="html_items/search" method="post" >

    <!-- Criteria --> 
    <div style="float:none;">
      <label>Content Provider </label>
      <select multiple id="content_provider" name="content_provider">
        <option value="FLR">Flare</option>
        <option value="SLDT">Slashdot</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

  </form>
```

fig. 1

Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
 
content_provider            FLR
 
content_provider            SLDT
 
fig. 2

PARAMs[{"content_provider"=>"SLDT", "controller"=>"html_items", "action"=>"search"}]
 
...
 
fig. 3

Thanks 
 
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that if you want to create an array of the elements that are selected you need to name your `<select>` something like `<select name='foo[]'>`

Next... If nothing is selected nothing will show up. This makes sense, but it stumped me for a bit.  I was doing ajax where the left select was search results and the right was the completed list.

I just added a `.click(function(){});` to my submit button to set every item on the left to selected with jQuery and the items showed up in the parameters as an array.  In the below example you should see the first item show up.

```
<select multiple id="content_provider" name="content_provider">
        <option value="FLR" selected>Flare</option>
        <option value="SLDT">Slashdot</option>
</select>
```